# get Node Value in soap response JAVA

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am trying to read 2 values from a WS SOAP response. at the moment i am unable to do so, iv'e tried multiple ways with no success.

Im interested only on the OperationStatus and SessionId.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <DoLoginResponse xmlns="censored">
         <DoLoginResult>
            <OperationStatus>true</OperationStatus>
            <StatusMessage/>
            <SecurityProfile>
               <User>
                  <UserID>720eeac1-7134-4587-b81d-b7431718c51b</UserID>
               </User>
               <Session>
                  <SessionId>eb63f534-322f-4014-88e0-72e6a6a5b167</SessionId>
               </Session>
               <IsFirstLogon>false</IsFirstLogon>
               <IsSystemOwner>true</IsSystemOwner>
            </SecurityProfile>
            <Authenticated>true</Authenticated>
            <UpgradeRecommended>true</UpgradeRecommended>
         </DoLoginResult>
      </DoLoginResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is what i have coded so far.

```
SOAPBody sb = response.getSOAPBody();
Node LoginResponse = (Node)sb.getFirstChild();
Node LoginResult = (Node)LoginResponse.getFirstChild();
Node OperationStatus = (Node)LoginResult.getFirstChild();

if(OperationStatus.getFirstChild().getTextContent()=="true"){
      _auth = true;
      _Session = "";//get SessionId here

}else{
      _auth = false;
      return response;
 }
```

for some reason i am never getting inside my if statement, therefore i dont know how to acomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the node by using getElementsByTagName and comparing the String values by using the equals method.

`Node OperationStatus =  sb.getElementsByTagName("OperationStatus").item(0);
if("true".equals(OperationStatus.getFirstChild().getTextContent()))
...`